# Identify areas where Bulk API V1 is used in org

Tags: apex, bulk-api

I am looking into impact of upgrading Bulk API V1 to V2. First, I have to identify areas where Bulk Api V1 is leveraged. But I am not sure what are things I should check. So, what all process should I check in my org?

Comment: In case you have event monitoring enabled, you can use [Bulk API Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_bulkapi.htm) to identify

Comment: You could also check the “Bulk Data Load Jobs” page in Setup to see if the job runs in V1 or V2

Comment: Yes, I can see Bulk API version in “Bulk Data Load Jobs” and operation type

Answer (score 0):

All Salesforce API transactions are recorded in Event Monitoring logs.

Event Monitoring typically requires a specific license, but Salesforce has exposed the [API Total Usage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_apitotalusage.htm) (ApiTotalUsage) event to all customers for free so that you can monitor legacy API consumption.

You can use this event to detect Bulk API V1 and other legacy API calls.  An open-source apex utility tool is also available to automate this process.  You can find more information in this [developer blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/08/make-api-version-retirements-a-no-op) which might be helpful.

Comment: "Legacy" as defined by `ApiTotalUsage` will only show calls to APIs up to version 30 since [v30 is the cutoff for retirement in Summer '22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000354473&type=1). Not useful for newer orgs.